# GE stackable Washer/Dryer Combo wont stop spinning

Tags: electrical, water, repair, washer, timer

I have a GE stackable washer/Dryer Combo (GUD24ESSMWW).  During the regular wash cycle, it continues until the drain and spin cycle and then it doesn't stop spinning until you hit the pause/stop button.  If I change my selection and then select the quick rinse cycle, it will finish the cycle, but then it'll restart the quick rinse cycle until I hit the pause/stop button.  I'm thinking it's the timer, but the only timer is located behind the dryer selection knob.  Does that timer also control the washer, or is there another timer I should look for?  The washer knob only has what looks like a control board prior to going to the main computer for the combo.

Comment: sounds like you need to read the user manual

Comment: Is it new enough to still be under warranty? How old is it and has it always done this or is it a new development?